# "Nested" type constraints in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Suppose I have a class

```
TController<T_Ui: TGui; T_Man: TManager> = class
end;
```

If I try to use this class as a constraint for a generic procedure like this:

```
procedure MyProc<T: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>>(ACont: T);
```

I get an error `undefined identifier T_Ui`.

Is there a shorter way to define the procedure than

```
procedure MyProc<T_Ui: TGui; TMan: TManager; T: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>>(ACont: T);
```

if all that I want is constraint T to the TController type?

**Edited:**

If I could define:

```
procedure MyProc<T: TController<*, *>>(ACont: T);
```

everything should be clear for the compiler.

My problem is, that instead of writing

```
MyProc<TMyController>(Cont);
```

I need to write

```
MyProc<TMyUi, TMyManager, TMyController>(Cont);
```

Comment: If you have to use generics then @DavidHeffernan's answer is enough I think. However do not forget about class types like `type TGuiClass = class of TGui;` and so on, which you can pass as parameters, store in variables and use them as usual types.

Comment: @Abelisto For my specific problem generics is the way to go, but thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure MyProc<T: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>>(ACont: T);
```

Let's consider what this means. This is a generic method with one generic parameter `T` which is a class that must derive from `TController<T_Ui, T_Man>`. Since `T_Ui` and `T_Man` are not generic parameters, the compiler has to interpret them as concrete types. You did not define types of that name, hence the compiler error.

But of course you don't want the compiler to treat `T_Ui` and `T_Man` as concrete types. You mean them to be generic parameters. In which case you have to declare them as such.

```
procedure MyProc<T_Ui: TGui; TMan: TManager; T: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>>(ACont: T);
```

Or perhaps like this.

```
procedure MyProc<T_Ui: TGui; TMan: TManager>(ACont: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>);
```

Which is simpler by way of removing the redundant parameter `T`.

In essence you are hoping for an implicit parametrization but that does not exist. Generic parameters must be declared explicitly.

Now, one technique that is sometimes used is to declare a non-generic class as the base type for your generic class.

```
type
  TController = class
    ....
  end;

  TController<T_Ui: TGui; T_Man: TManager> = class(TController)
    ....
  end;
```

Then you can write your generic method like this:

```
procedure MyProc<T: TController>(ACont: T);
```

Now, this approach requires that you can declare sufficient functionality in `TController`. If `MyProc` needs to call methods that can only be declared in a generic class derived from `TController`, then this approach is of no use to you.

Comment: You are right concerning the error. I hoped there would exist some syntactic sugar to get this through. I'm aware of the solution to have a none-generic base class, but this is of no use for me.

Comment: About your second suggestion. It is more simple and general to declare interface instead of class: `TController<T_Ui: TGui; T_Man: TManager> = class(IController)` and then `procedure MyProc(ACont: IController);`

Comment: @Abelisto It depends on whether you wish to use interface inheritance or implementation inheritance. Or maybe even both.

Comment: `procedure MyProc<T_Ui: TGui; TMan: TManager>(ACont: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>);` is useful if you only need functionality of the base class TController<T_Ui, TMan>

Comment: If you specify a third parameter, what can you do with it? You can only use functionality that you constrain for. Anyway, you asked about implicit parameters, and they don't exist. I think you know all there is to know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I need ACont to be generic in the first place, then the third parameter is only redundant if this need is fully defined by T_Ui and T_Man. Anyway, I asked a question, you gave a qualified answer - thank you very much.

Comment: The answer is not qualified. The third parameter would let you write non-generic code based on the specific subclass supplied. Usually you want to write generic code and in that case the third parameter is redundant.

Comment: I admit, that choosing a procedure as an example might not have been the best choice in this context, but you won't deny that 
having the third param might be a necessity in certain contexts. However, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AloisHeimer Actually I do deny that. Well, in the sense, that you can only make use of it with non-generic code. That is code that switches behaviour based on the actual type supplied. Without such non-generic code, and with the third parameter, `T: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>`, all you can do with `ACont` is use functionality in `TController<T_Ui, T_Man>`. It doesn't matter if you call the function with a more derived `T`, the generic method cannot use that more derived functionality.

Comment: I meant a more general context, for example `function GetController<T: TController<T_Ui, T_Man>>(): T;`. 
And even the original procedure example might for instance create an object, that makes use of generics without switching behaviour on type.

Comment: OK, I grant you that. I had not considered such options.